# Symfony cache:clear Failed to remove directory

Tags: php, linux, symfony, vagrant

I am unable to successfully run cache clear on my **Symfony** application. I have set the permissions to the `/var/cache directory as 777`. But still get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]   Failed to
> remove directory "/vagrant/app/var/cache/de~/pools": .

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

This was working before whilst I was using the file sharing type: nfs.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my VM to run the latest version (1.9.5) of vagrant. Was then able to use nfs, see:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
```

Comment: Which config file should we add config.vm.synced_folder to?

Comment: @Henry `Vagrantfile` :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you changed the permissions on the cachefolder recursively, and not just one the cache folder itself, (also, try chmod'ing from the host instead of the guest)

EDIT:

if ***PURELY FOR DEVELOPMENT***, setup your vagrant shared folder like so:

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "/home/git/-something-", "/var/www/-something-/public_html", owner: "-something-", group: "nginx", mount_options: ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]
```

Comment: Yes I ran chmod -R 777 /var/cache from the host machine but it still results in the same ^ error when I run console/bin cache:clear

Comment: try the dev only solution i edited into the above post

Comment: So I can see that everything now has permissions 777 but it still wont clear the cache it just gets stuck on this directory: /vagrant/app/var/cache/de~/pools really strange. I did have this working before whilst using the synced_folder type: nfs. However recently I have been experiencing issues with nfs and have reverted to using the default file sharing, but have since run into the issue with clearing the cache. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/927273/vagrant-up-throws-the-following-command-responded-with-a-non-zero-exit-status?noredirect=1#